# titletoc: How to match the numbering format in the table of contents to that of the section titles?

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

In a document class, I edited the numbering format (with color gray and Euler font) of sections and subsections using `titlesec`. However, I don't know how to apply the same style to the labels in table of contents.

The problem is that I only wish to modify the numbering format on the title, which means one cannot modify `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` etc. (unless there is a way to do this locally, I tried to change them in `\titleformat` and then change them back in the last `[...]` argument, but this didn't work), yet the `\thecontentslabel` of `titletoc` seems to use the value of them. With this restriction, how can the numbering format be applied also to the labels in table of contents?

[image]

Below is a MWE. (Yes it is ugly as this is just a "minimal" code demonstration)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}


\titleformat{\section}
    {\centering}
    {\textcolor{gray}{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}\arabic{section}}}{.75em}
    {#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont}
    {}{0pt}
    {\uline{\textcolor{gray}{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}\arabic{section}$.$\arabic{subsection}}\nobreakspace\textcolor{gray}{$|$}\nobreakspace #1}}


\titlecontents{section}
    [2em] % i.e., 0em (part) + 2em
    {\normalfont}
    {\contentslabel{1.75em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.75em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{\textcolor{gray!30}{.}}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
    [4.5em] % i.e., 2em (section) + 2.5em
    {\normalfont}
    {\contentslabel{2.25em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.25em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{\textcolor{gray!30}{.}}\contentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}

\subsection{Test subsection}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your ToC do you want the section titles centered as in your main document? Do you want the subsection titles left adjusted (and presumably underlined)? I have never used `titlesec` or `titletoc`.

Comment: @PeterWilson I'm fine with the current position, indentation and spacing of the ToC (though it certainly can be changed if there are better ideas), it's just the style of the numbering that is troubling me: I want them to be gray and with Euler font, as with the section titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want (“same style” is ambiguous).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\eul}[1]{{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\eulernumber}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \eul{##1} }
  \textcolor{gray}{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {.}}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\titleformat{\section}
    {\filcenter}
    {\eulernumber{\thesection}}
    {.75em}
    {#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont}
    {}{0pt}
    {%
     \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c|l@{}}
     \eulernumber{\thesubsection} & #1\\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}%
    }

\titlecontents{section}
    [2em] % i.e., 0em (part) + 2em
    {\normalfont}
    {\eulernumber{\thecontentslabel}\enspace}
    {}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{\textcolor{gray!30}{.}}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
    [4.5em] % i.e., 2em (section) + 2.5em
    {\normalfont}
    {\eulernumber{\thecontentslabel}\enspace}
    {}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{\textcolor{gray!30}{.}}\contentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}

\subsection{Test subsection}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a pretty elegant method.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I think you want.

```
% tocfontprob.tex  SE 636705

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% change the color and font of ToC section numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\bgroup \color{gray}{} \usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\egroup}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section {First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Another subsection}

\end{document}
```

Change the color and font to suit you. Read the `tocloft` manual for more information. BTW I'm not sure how well `tocloft` works with your use of the `title...` packages.

Comment: Thank you for this. I used to use your `tocloft` and I think that it can work reasonably well together with `titlesec`. However I have already defined most styles with `titletoc` (as it is from the same author of `titlesec`, compatibility shall never be a problem) and it would mean to have more work for transferring them into the `tocloft` version, and actually I have found an indirect method to achieve the desired style. But it is always glad to know that there is a simpler way, I might consider rewriting the code with this when there's enough spare time.